# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use') in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a WordPress site and I don't know why I see this error in inspect
I don't know much about coding, if you need more information I will post it here .
Thank you for your attention

This is a screenshot from Inspect
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFk2Z.jpg)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: This error is happening because `wp.data` is `undefined`.

Comment: How have I defined it?

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same error and it seems to me that it is caused by the Load JavaScript deferred option of the cache handlers (wp-rocket in my case).
try disabling the Load JavaScript deferred option

Comment: This should be a comment that adds a possible path to lead to an answer. This is not really an answer to the question asked.